# Can a function that takes a reference be passed as a closure argument that will provide owned values?

Tags: rust, closures

I am trying to simplify my closures, but I had a problem converting my closure to a reference to an associated function when the parameter is owned by the closure but the inner function call only expects a reference.

```
#![deny(clippy::pedantic)]

fn main() {
    let borrowed_structs = vec![BorrowedStruct, BorrowedStruct];

    //Selected into_iter specifically to reproduce the minimal scenario that closure gets value instead of reference
    borrowed_structs
        .into_iter()
        .for_each(|consumed_struct: BorrowedStruct| MyStruct::my_method(&consumed_struct));
    // I want to write it with static method reference like following line:
    // for_each(MyStruct::my_method);
}

struct MyStruct;
struct BorrowedStruct;

impl MyStruct {
    fn my_method(prm: &BorrowedStruct) {
        prm.say_hello();
    }
}

impl BorrowedStruct {
    fn say_hello(&self) {
        println!("hello");
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b3adb8d44250b65dfc33dd53509e860f)

Is it possible to simplify this code:

```
into_iter().for_each(|consumed_struct: BorrowedStruct| MyStruct::my_method(&consumed_struct));
```

To the following:

```
into_iter().for_each(MyStruct::my_method)
```

Note that `into_iter` here is only to reproduce to scenario that I own the value in my closure. I know that `iter` can be used in such scenario but it is not the real scenario that I am working on.

Comment: If you are able to change the `my_method` signature, you could write it as `fn my_method(prm: impl Borrow<BorrowedStruct>)` and accept both by-value and by-reference.

Comment: Note: Static methods are usually called [_associated functions_](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#associated-functions) in Rust.

Comment: @rodrigo, could you please share a reference what makes differ in between `&BorrowedStruct` and `impl Borrow<BorrowedStruct>`

Comment: Sure! The [official documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) is at the same time complete and confusing (at least for me). The TL;DR; thing is that `Borrow<T>` is implemente both for `T` and for `&T`, and even for `Cow<'a,T>`.

Comment: Additionally, the fact that it's an associated function has no bearing here — the same question is true of regular functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your general question is **no**. Types must match exactly when passing a function as a closure argument.

There are one-off workarounds, as shown in [rodrigo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55653241/155423), but the general solution is to simply take the reference yourself, as you've done:

```
something_taking_a_closure(|owned_value| some_function_or_method(&owned_value))
```

I actually [advocated for this case about two years ago](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/ergonomics-initiative-discussion-allowing-owned-values-where-references-are-expected/5161/2) as part of ergonomics revamp, but no one else seemed interested.

---

In your *specific* case, you can remove the type from the closure argument to make it more succinct:

```
.for_each(|consumed_struct| MyStruct::my_method(&consumed_struct))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a `for_each_ref` in trait `Iterator` yet. But you can write your own quite easily [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=95851de847e73b28c6eb5d4f94f0f029):

```
trait MyIterator {
    fn for_each_ref<F>(self, mut f: F)
    where
        Self: Iterator + Sized,
        F: FnMut(&Self::Item),
    {
        self.for_each(|x| f(&x));
    }
}
impl<I: Iterator> MyIterator for I {}
```

```
borrowed_structs
    .into_iter()
    .for_each_ref(MyStruct::my_method);
```

Another option, if you are able to change the prototype of the `my_method` function you can make it accept the value either by value or by reference with borrow:

```
impl MyStruct {
    fn my_method(prm: impl Borrow<BorrowedStruct>) {
        let prm = prm.borrow();
        prm.say_hello();
    }
}
```

And then your original code with `.for_each(MyStruct::my_method)` just works.

A third option is to use a generic wrapper function [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3f8d8c26a8fca34625b2c0891307ccac):

```
fn bind_by_ref<T>(mut f: impl FnMut(&T)) -> impl FnMut(T) {
    move |x| f(&x)
}
```

And then call the wrapped function with `.for_each(bind_by_ref(MyStruct::my_method));`.

Comment: Nice one but actually instead of this i'd prefer calling it explicitly in closure, `.for_each(|x|MyStruct::my_method(&x));`

Comment: @ÖmerErden: Sure, I prefer your option, too. But the OP ask explicitly how to simplify this code. You can argue that my answer does not simplify the code, but it actually _complicates_ it...

Comment: @rodrigo, I personally prefer that keep the code as it is as Ömer Erden's suggestion. Imho, writing such kind of specific functions for ref taking means a little boilerplate to me